# Space Spectrums

Tags: outer-space, three-dimensional

[image]
Three interstellar stations have observed a distant cluster of luminous spheres or gas clouds. The elements detected emits either red, blue or green wavelength but some of the gas clouds with another cloud behind it could result in mixed color.
These stations (X,Y, & Z) are positioned at right angle with each other with respect to a point within the cluster. And the photo images captured by their telescopes at the same instant are having exactly the same configuration. Connecting lines drawn on the pictures formed a 7 tipped star (see above). How shall they construct the 3-D plot of the cluster?

Comment: Are the colors mixed additively, like normal light? (That's what the presence of cyan seems to indicate.)

Comment: Usually green + blue makes cyan ,green + red makes yellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clouds are distributed

> in a 3×3×3 orthogonal grid

Top layer

> [image]

Middle layer

> [image]

Bottom layer

> [image]

The Y-axis view is achieved

> when looking from the top. The other two views are the side views.